# how verify that weblogic is up to date

Tags: java, weblogic

How can I verify that Oracle Weblogic is up to date ?
The administration console print 10.3.6.0 as weblogic version.
I visited Oracle site and the last version to download is 10.3.6 but I think that there is something missing because the server uptime is almost 2 years.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version is Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.3).
The version you are referring  is WebLogic Server 11gR1 PS5 (10.3.6) base version. Oracle is always updating the critical CPU patches.Which will help to fix well known bugs,vulnearabilies etc.So you can download the recent cpu bundle patch from oracle metalink support site(http://support.oracle.com go to patches and certifications --> choose recommended patch advisior --> enter weblogic version and os platform -->hit search and it will show you patches available (current one is 10.3.6.9 for weblogic 11g) and keep your weblogic updated.It is know way related with you server uptime.Server uptime will only show you that from how many days your server is running;it will never  show you that the  OS/weblogic or any other software installed  is up to date or not.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Doc ID 1470197.1 - Check this DOC ID on oracle's support site to download the latest patch set (currently 11) for WLS 10.3.6.

Also, if you are unsure of which patch set is already applied to your WLS you can always check it by running "java weblogic.version" from $WL_HOME (first set the environment by running . ./server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh  from $WL_HOME).

-Mayank